# Do similar matrices have the same number of eigenvectors proof? (i.e. is the sum of the dimensions of all their eigenspaces equal?)

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

I know from many online sources, including this [great one](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/similar-matrices-and-jordan-form/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.4sum.pdf), that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and the same number of eigenvectors (not necessarily the same exact eigenvectors). But how would I prove that the **number** of eigenvectors is the same.

In my specific case I have two $3×3$ matrices with the same eigenvalues (labda with multiplicity $3$) but they have eigenspace dimensions $2$ and $1$. (this tells us that they are not diagonalizable, but I want to prove that they are not similar between each other)

Comment: What do you mean by "number of eigenvectors"? If a matrix has an eigenvector, it has automatically infinitely many.

Comment: sorry, independent eigenvectors

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are independent eigenvectors of $B$, then $Cx$ and $Cy$ will be independent eigenvectors of $CBC^-$ (where $C^-$ is the inverse of matrix $C$). They are independent since $C$ is invertible and hence preserves linear independence.

Comment: @Antonio note that "the number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$" is the same thing as "the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$".

Answer (score 2):

The statement that you are trying to prove, as far as I can tell, is as follows:

> If $A$ and $B = SAS^{-1}$ are similar matrices and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then both matrices have the same (maximal) number of linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$.

---

The quick proof is as follows: it suffices to note that the map $T(x) = Sx$ defines an isomorphism between the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ and the eigenspace of $B$ associated with $\lambda$.

---

Here is a proof that avoids the notions of subspaces and dimension.

Suppose that $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent set of eigenvectors of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ (so $Av_j = \lambda v_j$ for $j=1,\dots,k$). Verify the following:

- If $Av = \lambda v$, then $B(Sv) = \lambda (Sv)$
- If $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent set, then $\{Sv_1,\dots,Sv_k\}$ is also  linearly independent.

It follows that $\{Sv_1,\dots,Sv_k\}$ is a linearly independent set of eigenvectors of $B$ associated with $\lambda$. In other words, $B$ has at least $k$ eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$. That is, $B$ has at least as many "eigenvectors" as $A$.

Symmetrically, if $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ is a linearly independent set of eigenvectors of $B$ associated with $\lambda$, then $\{S^{-1}w_1,\dots,S^{-1}w_k\}$ is a linearly independent set of eigenvectors of $A$ associated with $\lambda$. That is, $A$ has at least as many "eigenvectors" as $B$.

So, we find that the number for these two matrices must be the same.